# Why is tidyr nesting like this?

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm using the `nest` function from `tidyr` (version 0.4.0) to nest variables in a simple dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:4, type = c("B", "A", "B", "B")),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L),
                .Names = c("id", "type"))
df
#   id type
# 1  1    B
# 2  2    A
# 3  3    B
# 4  4    B

tidyr::nest(df, id)
#   type    data
# 1    B       2
# 2    A 1, 3, 4
```

Why does the first row of the nested dataframe not have `type = "A", data = 2`? Is this a bug or am I just misunderstanding what `nest` is supposed to do?

Comment: I get the correct output with "A" first. Try restarting your R session.

Comment: I've restarted R and tried running from within R, RStudio, and from the command line. Same output every time.

Comment: I also get the correct output with "A" first with an `ID` of 2. What other packages do you have loaded? Not that it should matter since you directly call `tidyr::nest`, but it'd be nice to know.

Comment: I can reproduce after updating to tidyr_0.4.0 - you might want to report this as an issue on the [github repository](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/issues)

Comment: Indeed, I'm running tidyr 0.4.0... that must be it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`tidyr 0.3.1` produces the correct output for me:

```
library(tidyr)

df <- structure(list(id = 1:4, type = c("B", "A", "B", "B")),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L),
                .Names = c("id", "type"))

df2 <- nest(df, id)
as.data.frame(df2)
#   type      id
# 1    A       2
# 2    B 1, 3, 4

sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
```